# Debian can't reboot and asking for root password (maintenance)

Tags: debian, reboot, maintenance

I'm experienced some file system errors on Debian (seems caused by RAID controller). Files system now seems fixed. I reinstalled broken packages with some broken config files. System boots normally. All services working.
Problem is if try reboot machine last message is something "unmounting all file systems". And after this message system asking for root password (looks like maintenance mode). How to solve this ?

Maybe something wrong with initscripts ? Any suggestions ?

EDIT: For me it looks like software problem.

Comment: What error messages were you getting and how did you fix them exactly/

Comment: What command are you using to do this? shutdown or reboot?

Comment: I'm can't rememeber all messages. but nothing strange. How to log messages after reboot ? /var/log/messages nothing shows. Yes I'm using reboot command

Answer (score 1):

#### Failing HDD?

When a system prompts you in this way it almost always means that the underlying HDDs are failing and/or have defects that require user intervention to repair.

I would go through the recovery process that it wants you to, to see if it can't recover the breaking/broken inode clusters and then use something like [HDAT2](http://www.hdat2.com/) and/or [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) on the system to try and repair the failing HDD.

If you're able to recover the HDD to a usable state, I would make sure to get a image/backup of it immediately since these are almost always symptoms of a HDD that will be failing in the near future.

#### Other reasons...

These messages can pop up if you are attempting to shutdown/reboot your system, and not doing it in the prescribed manner. I would recommend using the commands: `reboot`, `shutdown -r now`, or if you're turning it off all together, `shutdown -h now`.

#### References

- [Give root password for maintenance](https://serverfault.com/questions/372677/give-root-password-for-maintenance)

Comment: I have RAID. And it's status: Optimal. I'm using reboot command.

Comment: @maklaudas - Yeah just b/c the RAID status is optimal doesn't mean that the HDD's in the RAID are in good health.